# Prettyphoto API and other options

Tags: javascript, prettyphoto

I'm using PrettyPhoto to create a gallery. I've implemented API to start the gallery ASAP. This is the code, and it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery lightbox clone - prettyPhoto - by Stephane Caron</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $().prettyPhoto()
              api_images = ['images/fullscreen/2.jpg'];
              $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I need to remove some things from the gallery, like social buttons.
[Here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/) is the documentation, in the section "Customization" there's what I need for. I should use the option *social_tools* and set it to *false*, how can I insert this inside the code above?

Best regards

**Edit:** Resolved! Is just needed to put these instruction as prettyPhoto argument, something like these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $().prettyPhoto({social_tools: false, modal: true, allow_resize: true})
              api_images = ['images/fullscreen/2.jpg'];
              $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images);
              social_tools: false;  
            });
        </script>
```